# Remove duplicate rows from mysql table result

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a table named consignment which has some duplicate rows against column "service" where service='CLRC'.

```
select * from consignment where service='CLRC'
```

When i select the rows, i have total 2023 rows which includes duplicates.

I wrote the below query to delete the rows but i want to select them first to make sure its deleting the correct records.

When the select runs it returns 64431 records. Is that correct?

```
select t1.hawb FROM consignment t1
INNER JOIN consignment t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id < t2.id AND 
    t1.hawb = t2.hawb
    and t1.service='CLRC'
```

Comment: To delete you will `select t1.id`. If you delete by `hawb` , you will be accidentally deleting all the rows

Comment: I suppose you have duplicate rows excluding the id column, probably it's primary key, don't you?

Comment: "id" is the primary key which is unique for each row and i have duplicate rows against column "hawb" where " service='CLRC' "

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect your query to return the number of duplicates then no it is not correct.
The condition `t1.id < t2.id` will join every `id` of `t1` with all `id`s from `t2` that are greater resulting on more rows or less rows (in the case of only 2 duplicates) and rarely in the expected number.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d3mhr5ANuZgH74Q9zc4gwh/1).
If you want to see all the duplicates:

```
select * from consignment t
where t.service = 'CLRC' 
and exists (
  select 1 from consignment
  where service = t.service and id <> t.id and hawb = t.hawb 
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d3mhr5ANuZgH74Q9zc4gwh/6).
If you want to delete the duplicates and keep only the one ones with the max `id` for each `hawb` then:

```
delete from consignment
where service='CLRC'
and id not in (
  select id from (
    select max(id) id from consignment
    where service='CLRC' 
    group by hawb
  ) t  
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d3mhr5ANuZgH74Q9zc4gwh/5).

Comment: the select returns 1954 records and when the change the delete keyword to select in the 2nd query it returns 2010 records. Is that fine?

Comment: the select still returns 2010 rows and the delete returns 1954 records.

Comment: The remaining 56 rows are the ones with the max id that were not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Include all the columns in the matching condition except id column, as being primary key :

```
delete t1 
  from consignment t1
  join consignment t2 
 where t1.id < t2.id 
   and t1.hawb = t2.hawb
   and t1.col1=t2.col1
   and t1.col2=t2.col2   
   ......
   and t1.service='CLRC';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=828640ca273a1732fee97ad0df07a835)</kbd>

You can check the number of duplicates by

```
select count(*) from
(
select distinct hawb, col1, col2, service --  (all columns except `id`)
  from consignment
) q
```

check whether this number equals number of deleted records just before commiting the changes.